# Release a SQL artifact in Maven

Tags: sql, maven-3, publishing, artifact

How do I tell Maven to also publish the SQL artifact for the DBA?

Here's the thing: when we release every new version of our Maven application, we need to publish two artifacts:

- The web application (e.g. `app-1.2.0.war` file) -- for the WebSphere guy.
- The database changes for this version (e.g. `dba-1.2.0.sql` file) -- for the DBA.

The SQL changes file is currently `src/main/database/dba.sql`, but I can change that dir or file name if necessary.

As of now Maven publishes the war artifact automatically (`mvn clean deploy`) to the artifact repository, and that's perfect. However, I wanted it to publish the SQL file at the same time, in the same command as well... and it doesn't.

How can I do that?

I see that we can tell Maven to publish extra artifacts (e.g. sources, javadoc) at once, so I guess it should be possible to publish SQL files as well, but this is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Build Helper plugin for that.

But the file name is computed from artifactid, version, type and classifier.

If you need to absolutely push a different name with a different artifactId, you will need either to `mvn deploy:deploy-file ...` (from a command in your CI or with an ant script in the pom) or create an additional pom file and launch maven against it.

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>src/main/database/dba.sql</file>
                  <type>sql</type>
                  <!-- <classifier>xxx</classifier> -->
                </artifact>
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

link to the source: https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: The section "Attach additional artifacts to your project" looks promising. Will test now. Thanks.

Comment: The "Build Helper plugin" was the solution to this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I ask you an extra question? The actual location of the file is `src/main/database-source/${project.version}/dba.sql`. If the file is not present (it happens in minor version changes) this plugin crashes. How can I skip its execution when the SQL file does not exist?

Comment: You can set the plugin a a profile and enable it with a condition on the file: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation